# Match all the dates in a dataframe that are equal to one of the dates in a vector

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a timeDate column and a different vector of dates. I want to set a new column in my df equal to 1 for all the dates in my dataframe that are equal to one of the dates in my vector. I could do a double for loop but there should be a faster way of doing this right? The dataset is very large

```
test <- c("2009-01-01 00:00:00 UTC", "2009-01-02 01:00:00 UTC",
          "2009-01-01 02:00:00 UTC", "2010-12-25 03:00:00 UTC",
          "2009-01-02 04:00:00 UTC", "2009-01-09 05:00:00 UTC")
df <- as.data.frame.POSIXlt(test)

dvec <- as.POSIXlt(c("2009-01-01","2010-12-25"), tz = "GMT")
```

Comment: hi, you want to delete  dublicate date?

Comment: No. I want to flag duplicate dates (cause I have a timestamp in my df)

Comment: then try this might help ```df <- test[!duplicated(test[c("DATE")]),]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the date of `test` with dates in `dvec`

```
df$flag <- +(as.Date(df$test) %in% as.Date(dvec))
df

df
#                 test flag
#1 2009-01-01 00:00:00    1
#2 2009-01-02 01:00:00    0
#3 2009-01-01 02:00:00    1
#4 2010-12-25 03:00:00    1
#5 2009-01-02 04:00:00    0
#6 2009-01-09 05:00:00    0
```

The `+` at the beginning of the command changes the logical values (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) returned from `%in%` to integer values (`1`/`0`) respectively.

**data**

```
test <- as.POSIXlt(c("2009-01-01 00:00:00 UTC", "2009-01-02 01:00:00 UTC",
                     "2009-01-01 02:00:00 UTC", "2010-12-25 03:00:00 UTC",
               "2009-01-02 04:00:00 UTC", "2009-01-09 05:00:00 UTC"), tz = "GMT")
df <- as.data.frame(test)
dvec <- as.POSIXlt(c("2009-01-01","2010-12-25"), tz = "GMT")
```

Comment: This worked in my actually dataset but failed in my test dataset for some reason. Maybe dates need to be sorted? Anyway thanks, I really appreciate it!!

Comment: This should flag all of them since we are comparing only the dates.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use dplyr:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(valid = as.Date(test) %in% as.Date(dvec))
#>                  test valid
#> 1 2009-01-01 00:00:00 FALSE
#> 2 2009-01-02 01:00:00 FALSE
#> 3 2009-01-01 02:00:00  TRUE
#> 4 2010-12-25 03:00:00  TRUE
#> 5 2009-01-02 04:00:00 FALSE
#> 6 2009-01-09 05:00:00 FALSE
```